# unable to override a Virtual Property from an inherited Class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

My Custom Sitecore control inherits from Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control. This Class defines the Property Value as follows:

```
public virtual string Value {
    get {
        return this.GetViewStateString("Value");
    }
    set {
        if (!(value != this.Value))
            return;
        this.SetViewStateString("Value", value);
    }
}
```

My custom class is defined as follows:

```
public class ClientProfileSelector : Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Control, IContentField {
    ...

    public override string Value {
        get {
            return this.MyOwnValue;
        }
        set {
            if (!(value != this.MyOwnValue))
                return;
            this.MyOwnValue = value;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The code of the entire class is available [here](https://pastebin.com/uFZUPrx6).

My class is automatically instantiated by Sitecore, but I know it is running because I can step into other methods defined therein. For example the method GetValue() in my custom class calls the field Value like so:

```
public string GetValue() {
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(CalculatedValue) ? CalculatedValue : Value;
}
```

but when I step over it after adding breakpoints in both my definition and the base class' one, the execution stops in the base class.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to debug this? Are you sure the getter/setter of the base-class is used? How do you instantiate your class?

Comment: Note that this is a *property*, not a field. There's no such thing as a virtual field.

Comment: Yes, of course I debugged it. My class is instantiated by Sitecore, and I know it's running because I can step into other methods of it. For example the method GetValue() in my custom class calls the field Value, but when I step into it I am getting the definition from its base class.

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi You could forestall some confusion here by explaining that in your question.

Comment: Ed Plunkett, my code is referencing the Property Value; I tried using this.Value or just plain Value, the outcome doesn't change.

Comment: Could you perhaps include your class definition as well?

Comment: Thanks. It would be a big help if you question were very, very specific about exactly what the symptoms are.

Comment: I know this style is in the base class but really `if (!(value != this.MyOwnValue))` should just be `if (value == this.MyOwnValue)` for readability

Comment: Ed, I added the declaration of my class; the entire class code is rather large, I added in a Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/uFZUPrx6

Comment: Um, from the looks of it you're doing the `this.GetViewStateString("Value");` in your ClientProfileSelector... ? that's not as you have it in your question. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Side note: the logic in your `GetValue` method is probably backwards from what you really want.

Comment: Jack A., yes, I edited it - I am not using MyOwnValue in the actual class, it was just meant as an example.

Comment: Efrain, there are several instances of my class trying to access the Property Value; I added one such example in the question.